# Copy editor badge

Tags: support, badges

I was looking at the [**copy editor**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor) badge:

According to [the badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor), only 275 people have earned this badge to date. That sounds rather low for the group of people who edited 500 posts?

I don't know what the requirements are for a post being counted towards this badge? I found [this query here on meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1851/copy-editor-progress). I don't know what the validity of that one is, but it doesn't seem to change at all for me?

Is there an additional requirement for a post to be considered an edit?

Comment: Information on Data.SE is updated monthly, therefore you are not able to see your edit count go up in real time.

Comment: `500` is **a lot** of edits. It means that you actually care about the quality of the site and are willing to do things you won't earn any rep for...

Comment: That's the first then pages of users (http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=10&tab=editors&filter=all) which is a lot.

Comment: I don't think it was retro-actively applied. So there may be a few people who didn't receive it, despite having more than 500 edits to their name.

Comment: I also think that there are "too few" users with the Copy Editor badge. And I think I've edited more than 500 posts. Maybe the description of the badge should be improved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, most users are here for the Q&A part.

But on the other hand, 275 people that are willing to devote part of their time to improve the (content of the) site is not that bad.

Comment: If you look at all the other counts, 275 is rather low, isn't it?

Comment: @Nanne - Edits on your *own* content don't count, so it's not as low when you think about it that way...people editing *other* user's content to improve it (en masse here) is more rare, that's why it's a gold badge :)

Comment: I know this :) , but that didn't change my initial thought that it feels rather low, but it seems I misread how many had the strunk&white (added 2 zeroes in my brain for some reason), so that might be the problem :) with my ocnfusion :)

Answer (score 6):

Edits to your own posts do not count towards the Stunk & White or Copy Editor badges. Also, tag only edits don't count. I'm not sure if repeated edits to the same post count multiple times, but I believe title and content edits count separately.

Comment: The 'tag only edits don't count' part could be mentioned on the badge description, it would make it clearer.